# Azure CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL usage for CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

We have "oauth2-style" credentials for Azure blob storage, and want to use those credentials to load/save data in Azure Synapse.  We issue a command like

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL MyCredential
WITH IDENTITY='myclientid@https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytenantid/oauth2/token' , SECRET='***'
```

This form works for COPY INTO command, e.g.

```
COPY INTO table (c1,c2,...)  FROM 'https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/container/folder/' 
WITH ( FILE_TYPE='CSV', 
CREDENTIAL=(IDENTITY= 'myclientid@https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytenantid/oauth2/token', SECRET='***')
)
```

But when I used the saved credential in a CREATE TABLE AS SELECT command

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyDataSource WITH (
LOCATION='wasb://azuredw-upload@myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/', 
CREDENTIAL=MyCredential
)
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE MyTable WITH (
   LOCATION='wasb://azuredw-upload@myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/test',
   DATA_SOURCE = MyDataSource,
   FILE_FORMAT = MyFormat
) AS
SELECT * FROM sometable
```

I get this:

```
Msg 105019, Level 16, State 1, Line 47
External file access failed due to internal error: 'Parameters provided to connect to the Azure storage account are not valid.'
```

Do oauth2-style credentials work for this?  If not, what do I need to use instead?

UPDATE:
It would appear that, despite much documentation to the contrary, the SAS form must be used

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL [SasTokenWrite]
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
     SECRET = '***'
```

As I mentioned, the documentation says:

> "When accessing Azure Storage Account (V2) or Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2, the IDENTITY must be SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE."

Yet my portal for the storage account shows: `Storage (general purpose v1)`

Can anyone explain why the SAS token is required for CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE command but not for COPY INTO?

UPDATE: After several code reviews and combining the ADL2 and ABS credential logic, I find that ABS simply does not work, but ADL2 does, and ABS credentials work with COPY INTO but not CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE.  I chalk this up to a bug in polybase.  If anyone can show a counter-example I would love to see it.

Comment: This is a good question. I would be asking the same. Literally can't find anything definitive. the issue you're encountering with the "CREATE TABLE AS SELECT" command might be related to the compatibility of OAuth2 credentials with external data sources and tables in Synapse. The error message makes me wonder if the parameters provided for Azure storage access are not valid, which could be a limitation or specific requirement in how Synapse handles these credentials for external data sources. Is this a standard protocol that usually works? Following for updates.

Comment: From what I can read, this is the correct form to use.  I'll have to double check my credentials and make sure they are the same thing being used during the load (which works).

Comment: See my update, no idea why SAS form is needed here.

Comment: If the documentation and your experience suggest that SAS is needed for CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE despite the storage account being general purpose v1, it might be a specific requirement or limitation of the external table feature in Synapse or a nuance in how authentication is handled in this context.

Comment: No doubt.  Polybase always makes me nervous; too many moving parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the SAS token required for CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE command but not for COPY INTO?

In COPY INTO  `SAS` is also supported. As you see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/copy-into-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest#credential-identity---secret--) there is table mentioned which file format supports which authentication method, `SAS` is supported for all file formats.

> Do oauth2-style credentials work for this? If not, what do I need to use instead?

**As far as  `oauth2-style` credentials it is [supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest&preserve-view=true&tabs=dedicated#b-create-external-data-source-to-reference-azure-data-lake-store-gen-1-or-2-using-a-service-principal) for both ADLS Gen1 and ADLS Gen 2** the issue is might with blob storage.

While connection ADLS with `oauth2` credentials you need to use **abfss endpoint**

```sql
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL ADLS_credential
WITH
    IDENTITY = 'ClientId@https://login.microsoftonline.com/42f988bf-85f1-41af-91ab-2d2cd011da47/oauth2/token',
    SECRET = 'secret';

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE AzureDataLakeStore
WITH (
    LOCATION = 'abfss://ContainerName@StorageAccountName.dfs.core.windows.net',
    CREDENTIAL = ADLS_credential,
    TYPE = HADOOP
);
```

Comment: This tracks, thank you!

Comment: Thanks.  The page you linked does say that the SERVICE PRINCIPAL is supported for Blob Storage with CSV format.  I'll try to understand why my case isn't working.

Comment: As I mentioned in my last UPDATE in the description, this works with ADL2 but not ABS, and it works with ABS for COPY INTO a table from cloud storage, but not for CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AS into storage.  I'm calling this s defect in polybase.